# Minha própria pergunta está na fila de moderação e não sai de lá

Tags: bug, suporte, status-nãorepro

Há um ícone "incomodando" em cada acesso ao site. Veja a imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O primeiro ícone (com o número `1` nele) diz que há uma postagem marcada para moderação. Ao clicar, vejo que é uma resposta minha à pergunta [Como deixar tab bootstrap ativa após clicar em paginação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/909/como-deixar-tab-bootstrap-ativa-apos-clicar-em-paginacao/913#913).

Bem, o que aconteceu foi que, embora a minha resposta esteja correta, algumas pessoas a marcaram como "inválida" e o comentário foi "qualidade muito baixa".

É para ser assim mesmo? Eu poderia ter moderado minha própria pergunta? Será que ela está pendente porque falta outra pessoa moderar?

Comment: **Pode** ser duplicata de http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/331/notificacao-de-sinalizadores-incorreta

Comment: @bigown Estou achando que é duplicata, sim. Para mim já está assim há dois dias.

Comment: @bigown Devo excluí-la?

Comment: Se você acha que é duplicata mesmo, acho que sim.

Comment: O aviso deveria ter sumido depois de você ter revisado esse flag pela ferramenta de moderação (isso acho que é mesmo duplicata da minha pergunta). Agora, parece haver um outro bug: como a resposta é sua, acho que você nem deveria poder vê-la na fila de flags...

Comment: @bfavaretto Realmente, achei isso estranho.

Comment: Acho que vale você postar esse segundo caso como bug.

Comment: @bigown Editei a pergunta, acho que agora não seria uma duplicata.

Comment: @bfavaretto Editei a pergunta, acho que o objetivo está mais claro.

Comment: Só um comentário: não foi sua resposta que foi considerada "inválida", foi **a sinalização** que foi disputada (por 5 usuários). Ou seja, a maioria concorda que sua resposta **não possui** "qualidade muito baixa", e acha a flag inválida.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Não é que é mesmo!? Quando eu vi o texto *"Considerada inválida por 5 usuários"*, eu pensei que estava se referindo à resposta e não à sinalização.